# Beginner Creating GUI Using Python/Tkinter Need Button Coordination

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button, spyder

I have some experience with Python overall but none when it comes to creating a GUI. I'm trying to create a simple GUI using Tkinter where I have 4 frames inside of the main root window. A screenshot of what I have so far is below. The top left frame is just a reference image that I want to stay visible while using the GUI. The bottom left frame contains various radiobuttons that I need to figure how to coordinate to retrieve 2 images (one image to be displayed in the top right frame and another image to be displayed in the bottom right frame) after selecting the red "RUN!" button based on user selecting one radiobutton option under each orange font label (so user selects one radiobutton option under "Fault Type:", one radiobutton option under "# of DERs On:", and one radiobutton option under "Existing or Projected PV:" and then the "Run!" button is clicked, which, based on the radiobuttons chosen, retrieves one image for the top right frame and one image for the bottom right frame). The GUI also needs to be able to run as many times as it wants by simply refreshing the images in the top right and bottom right frames with each different selection of the radiobuttons and subsequent "RUN!" button click.

Here is my code, followed by a screenshot of what the code generates currently:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.title("Distribution Feeder Schematic")  # title of the GUI window
root.minsize(500, 500)  # width, height
root.maxsize(1500, 1000)  # specify the max size the window can expand to
root.config(bg="skyblue")  # specify background color
window_width = 1500
window_height = 1000
# get the screen dimension
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
# find the center point
center_x = int(screen_width/2 - window_width / 2)
center_y = int(screen_height/2 - window_height / 2)
# set the position of the window to the center of the screen
root.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{center_x}+{center_y}')

# Create top/bottom left, top right, and bottom right frames
top_left_frame = Frame(root, width=740, height=770, bg='white')
top_left_frame.place(x=5, y=0)

bot_left_frame = Frame(root, width=740, height=220, bg='grey')
bot_left_frame.place(x=5, y=775)

top_right_frame = Frame(root, width=745, height=490, bg='grey')
top_right_frame.place(x=750, y=0)

bot_right_frame = Frame(root, width=745, height=490, bg='grey')
bot_right_frame.place(x=750, y=500)

# Create frames and labels in left_frame
Label(top_left_frame, text="Feeder Overview", font=("Calibri, 15"), bg= 'white').place(x=320, y=0)
# load image to be "edited"
feeder = Image.open("Feeder_ScreenShot.png")
image2 = feeder.resize((740, 770), Image.ANTIALIAS)
feeder2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image2)
Label(top_left_frame, image=feeder2).place(x=0, y=25)
Label(bot_left_frame, text="Simulation Parameters: Choose a Fault Type, # of DERs Online, and Existing or Projected PV online. Then Click RUN!").place(x=15, y=0)

L1 = Label(top_left_frame, text='<-- Fault\nLocation', bg = "white", fg = "green", font = ("Arial",28))
L1.place(x=400, y=700)
Fault_Type = Label(bot_left_frame, text = "Fault Type:", bg = "white", fg = "orange", font = ("Arial",18))
Fault_Type.place(x=5,y=35)

Number_DERs = Label(bot_left_frame, text = "# of DERs On:", bg = "white", fg = "orange", font = ("Arial",18))
Number_DERs.place(x=150,y=35)

PV = Label(bot_left_frame, text = "Existing or Projected PV:", bg = "white", fg = "orange", font = ("Arial",18))
PV.place(x=330,y=35)

def retrieve():
    print(Var1.get())

Var1 = IntVar()
Var2 = IntVar()
Var3 = IntVar()

Nada = Radiobutton(bot_left_frame, text = "None", variable = Var1, value = 0, command = retrieve)
Nada.place(x=5, y=75)
SLG = Radiobutton(bot_left_frame, text = "Single-Line-\nTo-Ground", variable = Var1, value = 1, command = retrieve)
SLG.place(x=5, y=110)
ThreePh = Radiobutton(bot_left_frame, text = "3-Phase", variable = Var1, value = 2, command = retrieve)
ThreePh.place(x=5, y=160)

ZeroDER = Radiobutton(bot_left_frame, text = "0", variable = Var2, value = 0, command = retrieve)
ZeroDER.place(x=150, y=75)
OneDER = Radiobutton(bot_left_frame, text = "1", variable = Var2, value = 1, command = retrieve)
OneDER.place(x=150, y=110)
TwoDER = Radiobutton(bot_left_frame, text = "2", variable = Var2, value = 2, command = retrieve)
TwoDER.place(x=150, y=145)
ThreeDER = Radiobutton(bot_left_frame, text = "3", variable = Var2, value = 3, command = retrieve)
ThreeDER.place(x=150, y=180)
FourDER = Radiobutton(bot_left_frame, text = "4", variable = Var2, value = 4, command = retrieve)
FourDER.place(x=200, y=75)
FiveDER = Radiobutton(bot_left_frame, text = "5", variable = Var2, value = 5, command = retrieve)
FiveDER.place(x=200, y=110)
SixDER = Radiobutton(bot_left_frame, text = "6", variable = Var2, value = 6, command = retrieve)
SixDER.place(x=200, y=145)


Existing_PV = Radiobutton(bot_left_frame, text = "Existing PV", variable = Var3, value = 0, command = retrieve)
Existing_PV.place(x=330, y=75)
Proj_PV = Radiobutton(bot_left_frame, text = "Projected \n(Future) PV", variable = Var3, value = 1, command = retrieve)
Proj_PV.place(x=330, y=110)

Run = Button(bot_left_frame, text = "RUN!", bg="white", fg="red", font=("Arial",26), command = retrieve)
Run.place(x=600, y=105)


root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot of GUI:
[image: Screenshot of GUI]

Comment: You did not state what your problem is.  Note that you need to call `retrieve` only when `RUN!` button is clicked, not when selecting of parameters.

Comment: I need help with making the radiobuttons that are selected to coordinate with the run button so that whatever the combination of radiobuttons that are selected is, the RUN! button will then retrieve the desired images to be displayed in the top right and bottom right frames. I don't know how to do that. Should I even have created multiple frames or just do all of this on one root window? Do i need to use for loops or while loops or elif? When I click RUN!, how do I make the program get the desired images based on the radiobuttons selected? I need resources to point me in the right direction.

Comment: You know how to get the selections (like `Var1.get()` in `retrieve()`) and how to show an image (like in top-left frame), so I wonder why you don't know how to do what you want.

Comment: Bc I took those from other GUI examples and manipulated them to come up with what is shown. I don't have a solid grasp on the buttons. Do i need to store the radiobutton values inside of a variable and then call the variable whenever I press RUN! button? Do i need to use self or lambda or _init_ or any of these commands/functions? I don't have a good understanding on how to go about this. I don't understand if i need to have the buttons inside of a class or if I define a button in say, the bot-left frame, how to make that button cause an image to pop up in say, the top-right frame.

Comment: Like should I set the radiobuttons to a certain value, then if they're clicked that value will be stored somewhere, and then when I press RUN! how do I make the correct image pop up based on the stored values of the radiobuttons? Am i thinking about that correctly? Do I need to use for loops? Like if radbtn1==1, radbtn2==5, and radbtn3==0, Image.get(some image)? Something like that? I just do not understand how to make the buttons coordinate with each other to obtain the proper images that i want to pop up in the top right and bottom right frames. I appreciate you taking the time.